# dnf installs python3 modules only for platform-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, python-3.6, dnf

I'm currently working on an Ansible project which relies on python. For the ansbile package module the python3-dnf module is required.
On the destination Server (AlmaLinux 8.6) python3-dnf is already installed:

```
$ dnf install python3-dnf
Last metadata expiration check: 3:36:12 ago on Thu 06 Oct 2022 07:42:20 AM CEST.
Package python3-dnf-4.7.0-8.el8.alma.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I found out, that python3-dnf is only installed for the platform-python version 3.6:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
[...]
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root 4.0K Oct  6 11:08 dnf
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4.0K May 10 19:36 dnf-plugins
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   44 Sep  5 10:29 dnfpluginscore

$ /usr/libexec/platform-python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Sep 13 2022, 07:19:15)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dnf
>>>
```

Because when I try to import dnf with my latest installed python version 3.9:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Apr 21 2022, 08:39:11)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dnf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

So here is my question:
Is it possible to tell dnf ( `dnf install python3-dnf` ) to insall python modules not for the platform-python version but for the latest python version intalled or specify a python version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out, that python3-dnf is only installed for the platform-python version 3.6:

`dnf` can only install Python modules for the version of Python distributed with AlmaLinux. If you `dnf install python3`, you'll have a `/usr/bin/python3` binary that can see Python modules installed using `dnf`.

If you're installing Python 3.9 via some other mechanism, you'll need to manually manage your dependencies.

> I'm currently working on an Ansible project which relies on python.

Since you're using Ansible, one option is to simply use the platform-python version by setting `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/libexec/platform-python`.

Comment: "If you're installing Python 3.9 via some other mechanism, you'll need to manually manage your dependencies." How can I do this? Manualy compiling python? Or is 

And yes I could use the `ansible_python_interpreter` but this will break other things.
Currently I set this parameter to single ansible tasks but thats not the cleanest way to use the script on multiple hosts/environments.

Comment: How are you installing Python 3.9? Normally you would use `pip install` for managing Python dependencies, but for the `dnf` python module you will probably need to build it from source. You could create your own RPM package for Python 3.9 and install that using Ansible. Or just run `dnf` via the `command` module rather than using the `dnf` or `package` modules in your Ansible tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm now just using the platform-python version which makes the processes a lot easier.

Comment: On which part of the `ansible.cfg` file should be the option `ansible_python_interpreter`?  Is it possible to install the package for an other python executable?

Comment: You would typically set `ansible_python_interpreter` in your inventory. For more information start with [the FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-not-having-a-python-interpreter-at-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine)).